# zod validation for text editor values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation, zod

In my project using Zod validation. Zod validation in the schema

```
message: z
    .string({ required_error: "Message is required" }).trim()
    .min(1, { message: "Required" }),
```

There is "TextEditor" component used for the message field

```
<Grid className={styles.gridBox} item xs={12}>
          <Controller
            control={control}
            defaultValue={`< Company Name>  has invited you to participate in a feedback survey - ${formTitile}.`}
            name="message"
            rules={{}}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <TextEditor
                customClass={editorHeight}
                content={field.value}
                error={errors?.message ?? ""}
                setContent={field.onChange}
                label="Message"
              />
            )}
          />
        </Grid>
```

The data from the above component looks within the p tags

```
<p>text</p>
```

The issue is when giving space instead text it shows

```
<p>     </p>
```

so space validation using trim() is not working. So how do add space validation? Please give me some suggestions to fix this problem.

here react-hook-form is used and the schema name is "SchemaEmailShareSurvey",

```
 const onSubmit = (data: SchemaEmailShareSurvey) => {

    createForm({
      id: fromItemId,
      message: DOMPurify.sanitize(data.message),
      subject: data.subject,
      participants: result,
      useSharableLink: data.useSharableLink,
    });
    resetData();
  };
```

Comment: Could you share the code where the zod schema is actually used?

Comment: question is edited, and added the code.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `.trim()` *after* the call to `.min(1)`; otherwise space only text will never validate because the length will be zero after being trimmed.